What is the difference between UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewModel on Xamarin
When it comes down to UIPickerView, I've always used a UIPickerViewDataSource to fill my picker view with data. Recently I've found out that there is also an option to use a UIPickerViewModel, but I can only find documentation for Xamarin support. Is this something that only exists in Xamarin? And if so, what is the difference between the two?

This is speculation and might not be 100% correct, but I think this is the reason for the Xamarin.iOS team to come up with UIPickerViewModel, It was added for Xamarin.Forms/MAUI so that it is easier for them to create the Crossplatform controls that we use, Basically to use it in their Handlers/Renderers and since they were doing this any way they decided to keep the API public, that's the reason it does not have any documentation besides what you already added, I still use UIPickerViewDataSource in my iOS apps and the UIPickerViewModel never even came to mind.
Also notice how MAUI uses UIPickerViewModel: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Fmaui%20UIPickerViewModel&type=code
And does not use UIPickerViewDataSource: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Adotnet%2Fmaui+UIPickerViewDataSource&type=code
And weirdly enough they have hidden how they wrote UIPickerViewModel https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Axamarin%2Fxamarin-macios%20UIPickerViewModel&type=code

I tried to find out more about this, and it looks like UIPickerViewModel is a combination of UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate. Instead of creating two different classes, you can achieve the same thing by using the ViewModel, which contains methods from the other two classes. I've used it on my Xamarin iOS project, and it works perfectly.

I see that makes sense
